# what is qsTr in PyQt/QT?

Tags: qt, qml, pyqt5

I'm new in the world of Qt/PyQt/QML.

I'm creating a simple calculator using PyQt5 and QML.
In QML title is assigned by like below instead of a string.

```
title : qsTr("PyQt5 Love QML")
```

I've no idea what is the use of **qsTr** and What is the advantage of it.

Answer (score 7):

`qsTr` is for localization purposes. Later it will help Qt to gather strings to be translated to different languages. It is a common and recommended practice to wrap all the gui-strings in your code in `qsTr` (or just `tr` in case of C++/Qt) since then special Qt's tools like `lupdate` and `lrelease` could prepare nice translation files for you.

So, even if you do not plan to localize your app, it is recommended to wrap any string that will be displayed to user in `qsTr` to get a usefull habit.